# Email attached csv in grails mail?

Tags: csv, email, grails

Currently I am using the export plugin to create an csvfile on the fly on the server and then sending it to the browser via response.outputstream (done by the export plugin). Instead, what I want it to create the csv file and once done, email it to the user.looked into the export plugin code and it looks like it writes to the response output stream. How to read from this output stream, create a file, not store it to disc and just email it instead?

```
 def csv=responseArchive
            def csvDate=csv?.date
            def csvArchive=csv?.archive
            def csvReport=csv?.reporting
            def csvDelta=csv?.totals
            response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types['csv']
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.csv")
            List fields = ["date", "archive", "reporting", "totals"]
            Map labels = ["csvDate": "Date","csvArchive":"Archive","csvReport":"Reporting","csvDelta":"Totals"]
            // Formatter closure
            def upperCase = { domain, value ->
                return value.toUpperCase()
            }
            def title = { domain, value ->
                return domain?.date + ": "+domain?.archive+ ": " + domain?.reporting+ ": " + domain?.delta
            }
            String Csv="csv"
            Map formatters = [csv: upperCase]
            Map parameters = [title: "Report", "column.widths": [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]]
            exportService.export(Csv,response.outputStream, responseArchive, fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
    sendMail {
             multipart true
             to "test@gmail.com"
             body "Hello Watcher!"
             attachBytes "Some-File-Name.csv", "text/csv", contentOrder.getBytes("UTF-8")}
```

Comment: For email sending I use a personal class, in wich I use the following line `helper.addAttachment(file.name, new FileSystemResource(file));`. I can provide you this implementation

Comment: can you please provide the implementation

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the queuekit plugin I wrote a while back for grails. It shows you how to build a csv file on the fly. The plugin the has a background process which converts the output stream to file which it produces on the backend for download - https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/reports/QueuekitBaseReportsService.groovy#L421-L428 there are some videos on the plugin which might help you get an idea as in how to make a csv on the fly without the export plugin and do your own thing from there on

Comment: I would also suggest if you get to understand how the plugin works a feature which isn't covered much so far as I understand in the export plugin is the methods that you can use to export, above you are using http response. https://github.com/gpc/export/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugins/export/ExportService.groovy#L20 . On the above github project provided on the main page scroll down and look for `ExportPluginAdvancedReportingService:` this covers how to use `exportService.export(format, (OutputStream) out, domainClass.list(bean),formatters,parameters)` instead

Comment: Thanks Vahid its working